# Python eve: how to store images that are generated on the server?

Tags: python, gridfs, eve

I have a little python eve API, which accepts and successfully processes images as part of the multi-part. As part of the POST, I've implemented an event handler (which I append to `eve_app.on_insert_image`) which cuts out part of the image into chips. Here's the part of my schema that's relevant:

```
...
'things': {
     'type': 'list',
     'schema' : { 'type': 'dict',
                  'schema' : { 
                      'chip'     : { 'type' : 'media' },
                      'image_id' : { 'type' : 'string' },
                      'image_x'  : { 'type' : 'integer' },
                      'image_y'  : { 'type' : 'integer' }
                      }
                }
          },
 ...
```

The chips are designed to be stored in a list of objects where one of those fields is of type `media`. In the event handler, I currently do this:

```
retval, buff = cv2.imencode('.jpg', self.chip)
jpeg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buff)
return jpeg_as_text
```

but that appears to store the base 64 encoded string in the main mongo document (like so: `"chip" : "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBg...`) rather than in GridFS, where the source image is stored.

What's the best way, in Python Eve, to force a field/file to be stored in GridFS?

Thanks very much.